# boost mpi do I need to wait for multiple broad cast? c++

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

In my master function, I broadcast multiple objects:

```
    bool kill_all_slave=false;
    broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,periodicity_vector,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,J,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,x_range,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,y_range,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,z_range,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,component,0);

    broadcast(mpi_world,min_bound,0);
```

In my slave function, I receive them :

```
    while (kill_all_slave==false) {


        vector<tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int> > periodicity_vector;

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting to receive periodicity vector"<<endl;

        broadcast(mpi_world,periodicity_vector,0);

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting to J "<<endl;


        broadcast(mpi_world,J,0);

        int x_range,y_range,z_range;
        double min_bound;
        map<int,int> component;

        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 3rd set of the global parameters"<<endl;

        broadcast(mpi_world,x_range,0);
        broadcast(mpi_world,y_range,0);

        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 4th set of the global parameters"<<endl;
        broadcast(mpi_world,z_range,0);
        broadcast(mpi_world,component,0);
        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 5th set of the global parameters"<<endl;


        broadcast(mpi_world,min_bound,0);

        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" received 6th set of the global parameters"<<endl;

        bool stop = false;
        string status="initial";
        mpi_world.send(0, 0, status);
//        
        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to send to root status"<<endl;


        mpi_world.recv(0, 0, stop);

        cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive stop signal from root"<<endl;


        while(!stop) {

            map< tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>, map<set<tuple<int,int,int,int,int> >, double> > clustertype_periodic;

            // Wait for new job

            unsigned int job_id = 0;

            cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive stop job id from root"<<endl;

            mpi_world.recv(0, 0, job_id);

            cout<<"\n hello I am slave: "<<mpi_world.rank()<<" I am going to receive stop min bound from root"<<endl;


            mpi_world.recv(0, 1, min_bound);


            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()

            << "] Received job " << job_id << " from MASTER.\n"<<endl;

            // Perform "job"

            map<tuple<int,int,int,int>,int>  spin_tmp;
            double energy_tmp=0;

            tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int>  periodicity_now;
            {
                int i=job_id;
                periodicity_now=periodicity_vector[i];
                int a0=periodicity_now.get<0>();
                int a1=periodicity_now.get<1>();
                int a2=periodicity_now.get<2>();
                int a3=periodicity_now.get<3>();
                int a4=periodicity_now.get<4>();
                int a5=periodicity_now.get<5>();

                {
                    if (pseudo_mode) {



                        periodic(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,
                                 J, x_range, y_range, z_range, component,
                                 spin_tmp,
                                 energy_tmp,
                                 clustertype_periodic, min_bound, id,
                                 true, false, false,
                                 obscenely_verbose,global_parameters);

                        //                    {
                        //                        spin_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=spin_tmp;
                        //                        energy_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=energy_tmp;
                        //                    }
                    }
                    else if (basic_exact_mode){




                        periodic(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,
                                 J, x_range, y_range, z_range, component,
                                 spin_tmp,
                                 energy_tmp,
                                 clustertype_periodic, min_bound, id,
                                 false, true, false,
                                 obscenely_verbose,global_parameters);

                        //                    {
                        //                        spin_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=spin_tmp;
                        //                        energy_periodic[make_tuple(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)]=energy_tmp;
                        //                    }


                    }

                }
            }



            // Notify master that the job is done

            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()

            << "] Done with job " << job_id << ". Notifying MASTER.\n"<<endl;

            status="finish";

            mpi_world.send(0, 0,status);
//            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent status back to master"<<endl;

            //note here, I deliberated exclude cluster_type_periodic which may be the culprit of a lot of bad computing performance for realistic system

            //send periodicity, spin_tmp and energy_tmp

            //        and remember to send more detail;


            mpi_world.send(0, 1,spin_tmp);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent spin_tmp back to master"<<endl;
            mpi_world.send(0, 2,energy_tmp);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent energy_tmp back to master"<<endl;
            mpi_world.send(0, 3,periodicity_now);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have sent periodicity_now back to master"<<endl;


            // Check if a new job is coming

            mpi_world.recv(0, 0, stop);
            std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I have receive stop from master"<<endl;


        }


        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I am waiting for signal whether kill_all_slave"<<endl;


        broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);

        std::cout << "[SLAVE: " << mpi_world.rank()<< "] I receive kill_all_slave signal as "<<kill_all_slave<<endl;


    }
```

sometime segmentaiton fault would occur because one slave receives one broadcast but then cannot catch the next broadcast.... shall I add some usleep(1000) for the broadcast?

how could I handle this?

```
[SLAVE: 56] I receive kill_all_slave signal as 0
```

but then it did not receive the next round of broadcasting while other slave does receive.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if your slave processes are "receiving" the broadcasts in a while loop, then the master process must also be broadcasting the data in the same (or similar) while loop. Right now, it is clear that you have mismatched collective operations in some way and that is the first potential problem I see.

Comment: It seems that you are calling `broadcast(mpi_world,kill_all_slave,0);` last in your worker functions and first in the master function. Unless there is another broadcast in the workers just before the `while` loop, this is not going to work as expected. The order of collective calls in all ranks **must** be the same.

Comment: actually, the order is the same.... because if I produce 400 slaves, 399 works perfectly and sometimes just 1 slave does not catch the broadcast with 1% probability.... It is a total mysterious disaster....